# How can I know my App's download size prior Uploading, from my Apk size?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms, google-play

Is there any way from which I can get to know what will be my app's download size in playsotre before uploading? I have a working apk and made it using xamarin form.

Comment: Add a little step, You can follow this thread to get the apk file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows, then use "Analyze APK" option in Android Studio as Swetank's said, select the apk file by path, you can get the file size.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio, inside build tab you will find "Analyze APK" option. Upload your apk. There you will get to know download size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there any way if I don't have android studio?

Comment: @UpamSarmah VS do not have this function, you have to use AS to achieve that.